# How to structure a section properly?

Tags: website-design, color, text, interface-design

I have the following section on my site.

This is being viewed on a 1980p display so on a smaller resolution the left and right margin is reduced but the general layout remains relatively the same on desktop.

[image]

On mobile

[image]

I am no designer and feel there are some issues in this section, especially on desktop but I am not sure where.

I welcome all feedback.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you feel is a bit of inconsistency in alignment and sticking to a grid. There is no 'right or wrong' grid or alignment, but the use of such layout tools helps to create a perceived consistency and order.

Here are some examples to illustrate what I mean and how you could improve your designs. (By no means the best or only way to tackle this.)

Desktop: Is mostly centred, but the elements in the middle are a bit free-floating.

[image]

Here is how you could align them more consistent:

[image]

Mobile: Also centred, feels already quite right, but could still be improved, by aligning the outer edges as well.

[image]

[image]

There is a great free e-book by the famous designer Massimo Vignelli, called the 'The Vignelli Canon'. For further reading, I recommend to get it from his design firms website and start at page 40.
http://www.vignelli.com/home/bookmagazine/canon.html

Comment: Thank you. It definetly looks more consistency. In that case, should I avoid responsive grids, since it will stretch and shrink depending on the screening size

Comment: You are welcome. No, responsive grids are a great technical device.  Rather 'finetune/tweak' your containers and graphic elements, if that makes sense? A layout grid doesn't equal the responsive grid 100%, it's more the perceived order and overarching concept of axis of visual alignment ... a way of thinking about the look ... I am sorry that I can't explain this better.